# 2sxc loading BS4 template on BS3 Xcillion Theme

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a new install of DNN 9.8.1 and have installed 2sxc 11.11.04.  I am trying to create Tailwind "tlw1" editions of the content-templates but was having issues where the BS4 templates were loading even though the tailwind theme I am using has a koi.json file defining "tlw1" as the default css framework.

Thinking I had configured something wrong, I setup a test. I added the content layout with the image|text view to a page with the Xcillion theme.  I then added this remark `@* Bootstrap 4 Template *@` to the top of the BS4 template (added directly to the file using vs code) to make it easy to identify. Seeing Xcillion uses BS3, when I go to edit the template file, I expect the template from the ../BS3/Content folder to load. The editor however is loading the BS4 template from ../Content, not the BS3 template.

Do I not understand how koi is supposed to work, or is there possibly an issue with the koi implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If you use the `Edit Template` button in the 2sxc content module, the 2sxc editor opens in a new tab and always loads the BS4 template, even though your theme is using BS3 or other framework.  If you navigate to the BS3 folder (or other framework folder) through the file system, and edit the files directly with a code editor such as VS Code, the changes you make are displayed correctly as expected.

Comment: best mark as answered for future people with the same issue.